# Set custom properties to a visual in power bi embedded

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am creating custom power bi embedded visuals and saving it using report.save(). Can I add custom properties like id or anything else on the visual and save it. So next time if I getVisuals(), I will get that custom properties too.

Code

```
page.createVisual('areaChart').then((visual) => {
   visual.setProperty('id','1') or visual.AddDataField('id','1')
})

report.save()
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot set custom properties in powerbi visuals. The list of allowed properties is definite, you can find the list in the [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-report-authoring/wiki/Properties#available-properties).